# spring-data-cassandra unable to convert enum

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to have spring-data convert my enum type to and int field in cassandra but I'm getting the following exception:

```
Unexpected runtime exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Value 2 of type class com.twc.atg.td.dbo.client.ClassCode does not correspond to any CQL3 type
```

Here is the piece of code I'm using:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column("class_code")
public ClassCode classCode;
```

Comment: Which class is throwing this exception? Could you add more details to stack trace.

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution to this? Having the same problem

Comment: A quick answer - it seems like spring-data-cassandra doesn't support it.
The logic related to @Enumerated annotation implemented in com.datastax.driver.mapping, but the error is coming from org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.

Comment: Saying more, the package org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping is not used by spring-data-cassandra at all.
So here are two options - forget about this feature, or don't use spring-data-cassandra project :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not supported by **spring-data-cassandra**, you can implement this logic in getters/setters.

```
@Table
public class Writer {
    ...
    public enum WriterType {
        POET, DETECTIVE, JOUNALIST
    }

    ...
    @Column(value = "writer_type")
    private Integer writerType;

    ...
    public WriterType getWriterType() {
        return WriterType.values()[writerType];
    }

    public void setWriterType(WriterType writerType) {
        this.writerType = writerType.ordinal();
    }
```